# VB.Net Set search based on input and dropdown variables

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a scenario where a user can select a dropdown list to show some information. They can also use an editor field to search for the information manually as well. I am currently pulling a value from the dropdown list as a variable. I need to first check to see if the editor field is null, if it is null then set the editor field to the same value as the variable from the dropdown. Then, if the user enters a different value in the editor field, then it will show that information. The final scenario is if the user has manually typed in a number in the editor field but then wants to select a different option from the dropdown, then set the editor field to the new value that was chosen from the dropdown instead. So far, I have the example below:

```
If String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchField) Then
    searchField = Codevaluefromdopdown
End If
```

This covers the first two scenarios where if its null then set the editor field value to the same value from dropdown. It also covers if user manually enters a value then use that value in the editor field.

I'm struggling with the final part where:

```
If dropdown value has changed Then
    searchfield = dropdown value
End If
```

Every time I enter a value in the editor field and then try and go and change the dropdown value, it keeps searching using the editor value rather than the dropdown value.

Any help around this would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: Please specify which events are used for each code.

Comment: You should show a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The dropdown should have keydown and validated events, so there are two solutions depending on the dropdown type.

```
    Private Sub CboDropdown_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs)  Handles CboDropdown.KeyDown
        If e.KeyValue=Keys.Tab OrElse e.KeyValue=Keys.Enter Then
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(CboDropdown.Text) Then
                searchfield = dropdown.text
            End If
        end if

    End Sub

'If the user cannot type into the dropdown, then look at the validated event ...

    Private Sub Dropdown_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Dropdown.Validated
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(CboDropdown.Text) Then
            searchvalue = CboDropdown.Text
        End If
    End Sub
'''
```